# Nape Resulting Impulses

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, nape

I'm trying to make the player body, when certain condition is met, to go up few "meters" then stop slowly in the "air" and come down.

The gravity is 600

```
public var gravity:Number = 600;
public var space:Space = new Space(new Vec2(0, gravity));
```

I thought that for it to go up, the impulse.y should be at least -601, to contradict the force that pushes it down. Although, setting -600 (or even smaller) will shoot it upwards never to be seen again. (even -100).

Yes the impulse is in the update function which means it will constantly add the impulse making it faster per tick. However, when setting -20 it doesn't go up in the y, (it should eventually as impulse is being given to the body per tick).

```
switch (combo)
{
    case "W":
    break;

    case "WW":
    impulse.x = 0.0;
    impulse.y = -powerJump;
    mainChar.applyImpulse(impulse); 
    powerJump -= 5;
    break;  
}
```

This is not finished and it is not what is described above but it's the gist of it. When condition is met the player should go upwards and the impulse should lose it's force. The problem is I don't know how much is sufficient to counter the gravity impulse. I can do it by trial'n error but I'd rather know how it works, how much impulse is equivalent to gravity=600?

Comment: I think the problem is that you add the impulse in the loop. Try adding it out of the loop - just once. Then your logic about the impulse being bigger than the gravity should work. And it will automatically decrease speed as first it's an impulse and second - there is a gravity. Why you ever wanted it to be inside a loop?

Comment: Because I want the impulse to not be linear (impulse then fade). User presses W two times in a row which gives a fast jump into the air but quickly stop, hovers a bit than comes down. Figuring it out how to do this

Comment: Impulse is not linear by itself, when you have gravity with it. If you have opposite gravity, the impulse will constantly decrease while the gravity will remain the same.